# What is triggered everytime you change mailmerge-recipient? MS-Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Everytime I click the arrow (see pic), a function is triggered right?

I want to make a macro that runs everytime that funcion is triggered. What function is called and how do I declare the macro?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It has come to my attention that no event is triggered when pressing that button